# Unable to get HttpEventType.Response after HttpEventType.UploadProgress

Tags: angular, angular8

I am able to uploading the video on the server after that i want to get the response from api and push into the array.

But after uploading video unable to get the response

Component.ts

```
    const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', this.selectedFile);
    this.request = this.createTraining.uploadVideo(fd,{reportProgress: true,
      observe:'events'}).subscribe((event :HttpEvent<any>) =>{

        if(event.type == HttpEventType.UploadProgress){
          this.loaderService.hide();
          this.state = 'in';
          this.name = this.selectedFile.name;
          this.progress= Math.round (event.loaded / event.total*100) ;
          if(this.progress == 100){
            this.show = false;
            this.progress = 0;
            this.state = 'out';
            this.trainingItemList.push({name:this.name,order:null, type:this.selectedFile.type,path:null,question:null});
          }
        }
         **if(event.type == HttpEventType.Response) {
          console.log(event.body.message);**
        }
      },
      error=>{
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

Service

```
uploadVideo(video,progress):Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:8080/employee/upload',video,progress);
  }
```

I am trying to get the response after uploading the video but unable to get into the

```
if(event.type == HttpEventType.Response) {
          console.log(event.body.message);
```

[Api Response after upload which i want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNE9s.png)

Comment: Try accessing `event.body` instead of `event.body.message`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`message`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.11/packages/common/http/src/response.ts#L321) property is part of the [`HttpErrorResponse`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.11/packages/common/http/src/response.ts#L319) class. To access the response body of the type [`HttpResponse`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.11/packages/common/http/src/response.ts#L257), try to access only the [`body`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.11/packages/common/http/src/response.ts#L267) property.

Replace

```js
console.log(event.body.message);
```

with

```js
console.log(event.body);
```

Comment: I tried already but unable going into the if statement of the HttpEventType.Response.

Comment: @Shivam: Try to do a `console.log(event)` before the `if` condition and please post the results. See if the response actually reaches type `4`.